# How to access result of mySql query

Tags: javascript, mysql

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why I cannot access this data.  I am using a mySql query in order to return the id of the last entered record.

```
SELECT MAX(hca_id) FROM hca
```

It correctly returns: `{'Max(hca_id): 49}`

However, I need to set a variable to just use the `49`.

If I console.log(result) <-- Returns `{0:{MAX(hca_id): 49}`

If I console.log(result[0] <-- Returns `{MAX(hca_id): 49}`

If I console.log(result[0].MAX(hca_id)) <-- Fails to compile: `'hca_id` is not defined.

I'm sure it's late and I'm tired and missing something simple.  Would appreciate any help though as I've spent too much time on this.

Comment: which orm are you using?

Comment: Hey there, what does `console.log(result[0]['MAX(hca_id)']);` return?

Comment: Are you sure it returns `{'Max(hca_id): 49}`, not `{'MAX(hca_id): 49}`?

Comment: console.log(result[0].["MAX(hca_id)"]) ? If I understand it correctly you need to access the value by a key of an object

Comment: How about making life easier with aliases... `SELECT MAX(hca_id) AS max_hca_id FROM hca` and `result[0].max_hca_id`

Comment: Thank you Phil!  That was exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly!